# Am I busy making multiple requests?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code that opens a file stream, reads a chunk and posts it to my web service. I want to know if this code is busy creating a request for each chunk? If this is the case it does not seem efficient. If my file is 10MB and I'm making a request for each 4KB then there are about 2500 requests being sent.

Here is the code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4KB
        // Read from file stream
        int bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                new ByteArrayContent(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            };

            // Post to server
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, formData);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read next buffer
            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to stream the byte array to the web service?

**Update**

If its a 10GB file the user needs to upload then it doesn't make sense to upload the entire file in one request. If the upload fails then the user can retry from the last chunk that got sent successfully. I would like to show upload progress aswell. I know its bad practice to open and close connections when making multiple requests but I'm not sure if the way I'm using HttpClient is just opening the connection, making all my requests, and then closing the connection or if I'm opening and closing the connection in each while iteration.

Comment: 4KB is a piteously small chunk size. What are you gaining by chopping your uploads into such tiny pieces? I can't see how this might be an improvement on just sending the data in one go. 2500 requests? I've seen routers fail with less.

Comment: ...is there some constrain to this problem that you've failed to mention? Something like unreliable connection, timeouts, failure to complete larger uploads?

Comment: @TheGeneral If its a 10GB file the user needs to upload then it doesn't make sense to upload the entire file in one request. If the upload fails then the user can retry from the last chunk that got sent successfully. I would like to show upload progress aswell. I know its bad practice to open and close connections when making multiple requests but I'm not sure if the way I'm using HttpClient is just opening the connection, making all my requests, and then closing the connection or if I'm opening and closing the connection in each while iteration.

Comment: @PierreNortje ok that makes a lot more sense now, hopefully someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use StreamContent to post the entire file.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()
using (var inputStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
   var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
   {
      new StreamContent(inputStream)
   };
   var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, formData);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to post the entire file. I am busy chunking the file into bytes and uploading them. I am asking if my current code is making a request for each 4KB it is uploading and if there is a better way to stream the file to the web service.